# java drawing a rainbow

Tags: java, drawing

The program can run but it's not outputting what I want it to output. See, I want 7 concentric arcs which colored as a rainbow. What I'm getting is 7 concentric arcs colored red and yellow. I need the colors in this order:

red, yellow, pink, green, purple, orange, blue

What do I need to add or change? I'm using if else statements to alternate between colors. Which is why it's alternating between red and yellow. I added another set of if else within the other if else statements, I am thinking that I can use them to further alternate.

I'm pretty new to java and loops. I was thinking I could use for, while, if else or do loops for the colors.

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.*;
public class rainbowpanel extends JPanel
{

private final int MAX_WIDTH = 300, NUM_RINGS = 7, RING_WIDTH = 20;



public rainbowpanel ()
{
setBackground (Color.white);
setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300,300));
}




    public void paintComponent (Graphics page)

    {
        super.paintComponent (page);
        int x = 0, y = 0, diameter = MAX_WIDTH;
        page.setColor (Color.yellow);
     for (int count = 0; count < NUM_RINGS; count++)


        {
            if (page.getColor() == Color.yellow) // alternate colors
            page.setColor (Color.red);
            else
            page.setColor (Color.yellow);
            page.fillArc (x, y, diameter, diameter, 0, 180);




            diameter -= (2 * RING_WIDTH);
            x += RING_WIDTH;
            y += RING_WIDTH;
            }



            {
            if (page.getColor() == Color.yellow) // alternate colors
                page.setColor (Color.pink);
            else
                page.setColor (Color.orange);
                   page.fillArc (x, y, diameter, diameter, 0, 180);



            //diameter -= (2 * RING_WIDTH);
            //x += RING_WIDTH;
            //y += RING_WIDTH;
}




            page.setColor (Color.white);
            page.fillArc (x, y, diameter, diameter, 0, 180);
}
}
```

You have to run it from this file:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class rainbow

{

public static void main (String[] args)
{
JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Rainbow");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


rainbowpanel panel = new rainbowpanel();
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Create a `colors = Color[7]`, initialize with the values that you want, use `colors[count]`

Comment: What do you mean BackSlash? Are you addressing my code or how I asked this question?

Comment: Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow.

Comment: Okay, I changed it a little, how's that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
{
    super.paintComponent (page);
    int x = 0, y = 0, diameter = MAX_WIDTH;

    Color myColors[] = { Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.pink, Color.green, Color.purple, Color.orange, Color.blue };

    for (int count = 0; count < NUM_RINGS; count++)
    {
        page.setColor (myColors[count%NUM_RINGS]);
        page.fillArc (x, y, diameter, diameter, 0, 180);

        diameter -= (2 * RING_WIDTH);
        x += RING_WIDTH;
        y += RING_WIDTH;
    }
}
```

You should suffice with just one for cycle with all the drawing. The `count%NUM_RINGS` will prevent array out of bounds error if you set more rings than you have colors, they will cycle from beginning.

Comment: Thank you. I did a slight edit and added another ring and added the color white, this way the last ring made the base of the rainbow look "clear". I like to keep my code simple as possible and now it definitely is.

Comment: Got it! I just got a whole lot of hate for the formatting here. I'm glad you stuck it through.

Answer (score 0):

please try this code. This code is little bit tricky .I know this is not the professional  way to code .

```
public class rainbowpanel extends JPanel{
private final int MAX_WIDTH = 300, NUM_RINGS = 7, RING_WIDTH = 20;

public rainbowpanel ()
{
    setBackground (Color.white);
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension(300,300));
    }
public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
{
super.paintComponent (page);
int x = 0, y = 0, diameter = MAX_WIDTH;
page.setColor (Color.red);
for (int count = 0; count < 2; count++)
{
if (page.getColor() == Color.yellow) // alternate colors
page.setColor (Color.red);
else
page.setColor (Color.yellow);
page.fillArc (x, y, diameter, diameter, 0, 180);

diameter -= (2 * RING_WIDTH);
x += RING_WIDTH;
y += RING_WIDTH;
}
for (int count = 0; count < 2; count++)
{
if (page.getColor() == Color.blue) // alternate colors
page.setColor (Color.green);
else
page.setColor (Color.blue);
page.fillArc (x, y, diameter, diameter, 0, 180);

diameter -= (2 * RING_WIDTH);
x += RING_WIDTH;
y += RING_WIDTH;
}
for (int count = 0; count < 2; count++)
{
if (page.getColor() == Color.pink) // alternate colors
page.setColor (Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
else
page.setColor (Color.pink);
page.fillArc (x, y, diameter, diameter, 0, 180);

diameter -= (2 * RING_WIDTH);
x += RING_WIDTH;
y += RING_WIDTH;
}
for (int count = 0; count < 1; count++)
{
if (page.getColor() == Color.cyan) // alternate colors
page.setColor (Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
else
page.setColor (Color.cyan);
page.fillArc (x, y, diameter, diameter, 0, 180);

diameter -= (2 * RING_WIDTH);
x += RING_WIDTH;
y += RING_WIDTH;
}

}
}
```